# Input Field Required

Tags: json, laravel, validation, controller

im making simple data table CRUD. the create must able to have file input, in this context is image. but im encountering this problem where i think the input name isn't recognized by the validate request in controller bcs i did upload an image which only 50KB in size.

here's the input form

```
<form id="addTask" action="{{ route('create-data') }}" method="POST" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="container-fluid">                        
                            <div class="row">
@if (Auth::user()->role->name === 'Operator')
                                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-6">                                                                           
                                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control datepicker " id="datepicker" name="input_date" />
                                        <div class="mb-3">
                                            <label for="project" class="align-items-start">Project:</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" name="nama_project">
                                        </div>                                  
                                        <div class="mb-3">
                                            <label for="detail" class="align-items-start">Detail Project:</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" name="detail">
                                        </div>                                  
                                        <div class="mb-3">
                                            <label for="eta" class="align-items-start">ETA:</label>
                                            <div class="input-group date w-100" id="datepickerContainer">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="etapicker" name="eta_project"/>
                                                <span class="input-group-append">
                                                    <span class="input-group-text bg-light d-block">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                                    </span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mb-3">
                                            <label for="requestor" class="align-items-start">Request Name:</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" name="requestor">
                                        </div>                                    
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-0">                                
                                        <div class="mb-3">
                                            <label for="category" class="align-items-start">Category:</label>
                                            <select class="form-control w-100" id="category_project" name="category_project">
                                                <option selected>Pilih Kategori</option>
                                                <option value="Infrastructure">Infrastructure</option>
                                                <option value="Maintenance">Maintenance</option>
                                                <option value="Tool Store">Tool Store</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mb-3" >                                        
                                            <label for="status">Status</label>                                                            
                                                <select class="form-control w-100" id="status" name="status">
                                                <option selected>Select</option>
                                                <option value="Open">Open</option>
                                                <option value="On Progress">On Progress</option>
                                                <option value="Done">Done</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mb-3">
                                            <label for="photos">Image:</label>
                                            <input type="file" name="photos_img" id="photos">
                                        </div>                                                                                     
                                    </div>
                                @endif         
                                
                            </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

and this is my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
     {
         $validatedData = $request->validate([
             'eta_project' => 'required|date_format:m/d/Y',
             'requestor' => 'required',
             'pic_project' => 'nullable',
             'nama_project' => 'required',
             'detail' => 'required',
             'category_project' => 'required',
             'status' => 'nullable',
             'description_project' => 'nullable',
             'photos_img' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048|required'
         ]);
     
         $validatedData['input_date'] = now()->toDateString(); // Assuming 'input_date' is of type DATE
         // Format the dates using Carbon
         $validatedData['eta_project'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $validatedData['eta_project']);
     
         $imageName = 'none'; // Initialize imageName with null
     
         if ($request->hasFile('photos_img')) {
             // Get the file from the request
             $image = $request->file('photos_img');
             // Generate a unique name for the image file
             $imageName = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
             // Store the image file in the specified directory
             $image->storeAs('images', $imageName, 'public'); // Store the image in the public/images directory
             $validatedData['photos_img'] = $imageName; // Assign imageName to 'image' field
         }
        
         // Create a new record in the database
         $model = Project::create($validatedData);
     
         return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'data' => $model]);
     }
```

i even try to see if the error was happened while requesting but it seems already wrong since the input field name. i also struggling to understand the storing of the image